# Detect presolve status in pulp model

Tags: linear-programming, python, pulp, cbc, coin-or

I am running a model using pulp CBC and have few constraints in the model that may make the model infeasible if wrong input is given to the model.

I can see while my model runs that in case of infeasible model, I can see an output in terminal that says `presolve detects 1 infeasibility`. After this line my model starts solving and no surprise gives me an output that my solution is infeasible.

My question is, how can I stop my program if presolve is saying my model is infeasible? Is there any way to detect that as I don't want to spend time solving a model which presolve says is infeasible.

***Problem Background:***

I have a hard constraint in my model, which can make my model infeasible in some cases, I want my **program** (and not OR model) to detect this infeasibility and make that constraint soft.

One way to achieve this is let my complete program run and then detect `result_status` but as model can take quite some time to run and I don't want to spend time considering I have to take another run with *Soft Constraint*. I am thinking is there any way I can detect and stop my model if presolve say model is infeasible.

*LP File with some rows removed:*

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - "PATH" max sec 3000 ratio 1e-05 timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution "PATH"\f5c13890167e459ea27741f1c5d52d5c-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 95389 COLUMNS
At line 611896 RHS
At line 707281 BOUNDS
At line 707282 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 95384 rows, 175589 columns and 341444 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
seconds was changed from 1e+100 to 3000
ratioGap was changed from 0 to 1e-05
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Presolve determined that the problem was infeasible with tolerance of 1e-08
Analysis indicates model infeasible or unbounded
1 infeasibilities
Analysis indicates model infeasible or unbounded
Perturbing problem by 0.001% of 5262.5816 - largest nonzero change 0.0052725434 ( 9.7117787%) - largest zero change 0.0026361607
0  Obj -0 Primal inf 7.4173266e+08 (10627) Dual inf 1.383116e+10 (56881)
0  Obj -0 Primal inf 7.4173266e+08 (10627) Dual inf 6.2882648e+14 (66006)

Primal infeasible - objective value -6.0887206e+12
PrimalInfeasible objective -6.088720618e+12 - 108021 iterations time 88.622

Result - Linear relaxation infeasible

Enumerated nodes:           0
Total iterations:           0
Time (CPU seconds):         89.03
Time (Wallclock Seconds):   89.03

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       89.91   (Wallclock seconds):       89.91
```

Comment: if solution_status == "infeasible": break

does it useful for you? if not, could you explain your question detail? Thanks

Comment: It's not really useful as I will get this status after model has completed it's solve run which will take time. The benefit of using presolve status is that I can save some time if stop the model in the middle

Comment: @BhavyaBudhia, Welcome to OR.SE. It seems your problem does have a numerical issue. Usually, when a solver detects infeasibility in the problem structure and also in the pre-solving phase, it stops and prints a message like you see. Is it possible to share an LP file? Or at least the solver log?

Comment: @A.Omidi Hi, I have made some changes in the question to add more context and have attached LP file. Thanks

Comment: @BhavyaBudhia, thanks. Would you try using another solver to run and see the same behavior?

Comment: @A.Omidi it's not a solver problem. I know why my constraint will break and I expect it to break. When it will break I will make it soft. The reason it's not soft from the starting is because soft version of this constraint will take quite long to run.